# decreasing speed of software after adding new connection to new database file

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a database with EF 4, created and the files inside the database. `VarBinary(MAX)` I saved.

So far everything has been good.

A few days ago, we created another database and saved files in the format `VarBinary(MAX)`. We moved to the new database and in this case there are two connections.

In the project, we created the second one related to the new database that was created specifically for files, and the first one for the same previous database.

The problem started from here, when the first advertisement was posted, the customers immediately realized that the speed has slowed down and we can't do anything.

Previously, we used to move about 5000 file records in 30 seconds.
But after sending the publication and connecting the users to that database, the speed decreased so that it took about 14 minutes to insert 10 records.

Do you know what was the reason?

Here is the database table structure in both of databases:

```
USE [GoodsFileDb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [css].[ReceptionReceiptFiles]
(
    [ReceptionReceiptKind_Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ReceptionReceipt_Code] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [SMALLINT] NOT NULL,
    [Photo] [VARBINARY](MAX) NULL,
    [ReceptionReceiptFileType_Id] [INT] NULL,
    [PublishDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [ReceptionReceiptFileStateID] [INT] NULL,
    [AcceptDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [UserAccept] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_css.ReceptionReceiptFiles] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReceptionReceiptKind_Id] ASC,
                               [ReceptionReceipt_Code] ASC,
                               [Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

EF entity in C#:

```
[Table("ReceptionReceiptFiles", Schema = "css")]
public class ReceptionReceiptFile
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ReceptionReceiptKind_Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public long ReceptionReceipt_Code { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public int? ReceptionReceiptFileType_Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }
    public int? ReceptionReceiptFileStateID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReceptionReceiptFileStateID"), NotMapped]
    public virtual ReceptionReceiptFileState ReceptionReceiptFileStates { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AcceptDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public String UserAccept { get; set; }
}
```

The important thing is that I used to have a list that by clicking on each item in the same database, it uploaded and displayed the available photos that were in the database in the form of a banner.

But now it has to load and read the photos from the second database, which has caused the program to be extremely slow and strange.

I've checked indexes and there is no any problem. The two database tables are the same.

Comment: Blob fields are to always be avoided in a database if possible. If there is no other choices it should be in it's own table to not slow down queries

Comment: Dear Mr. @Franck first of all thanks for your quick reply. Actually the space of our first database that we used to save our data files is so huge. is there any way to save our files and load them in our window software without loosing speed. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can add detail about about the context? Why did you created new db? What is the diff between the old/new db? Why two connections?

Answer (score 1):

I probably won't be able to answer your question, without knowing your network hardware, but it's absolutely not normal to insert 10 records in 14 minutes. So one advice I can give You, is to **move the images out of the database**. It's not absolutely a good idea to store over 5000 images (photos and so on...) in a database. **FILE SYSTEMS were created and designed to store your files and pictures**, not SQL databases. Therefore, think about storing ONLY THE PATHS in your sql database (study a system to give them unique names), and put your image files into the folders of your hard disk server. I don't think You need to think about it for even a minute longer.